# Linq to SQL - how to make a select with conditions and return IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I can not find answers how to implement the following scenario (I do not know what to look for methods). I use `C#`, `.NET FW4.5`, `Linq` to SQL and design pattern repository.

If I want to select all devices, use this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get all Devices
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public IQueryable<Device> GetDevices()
{
    return myDataContext.Devices;
}
```

If I want to select device by ID, use this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get Device by ID
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public Device GetDevice(int id)
{
    return myDataContext.Devices.SingleOrDefault(
        d => d.intDeviceId == id);
}
```

But how can I implement the following situation?

Select all devices, where are some conditions (and return `IQueryable<Device>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like :

```
public IQueryable<Device> GetDeviceUsingPredicate(Expression<Func<Device,bool>> predicate)
{
    return myDataContext.Devices.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
}
```

To use with generics:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetDeviceUsingPredicate(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate)
{
    return myDataContext.GetTable<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. If I compare your and X.L.Ant answer, what is better method? What I see samples, reposity pattern have got N mehod, which every return something else. Your example is for universal use. Which way is better to go in terms of code maintenance in the future?

Comment: You can use generics to make a generic repository for your linq-to-sql entities as in updated answer. In terms of maintenance, I prefer generic way of doing things. It's up to your applications requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Only two notes (if someone should implement this): 1) must import the namespace System.Linq.Expressions 2) Sample coding: List<Device> listDevices = this.myDeviceRepository.GetDeviceUsingPredicate(d => d.bitIsRemoved == false).ToList();

Comment: Yes. You are right. But for usage with generics you have to make your repository generic and construct your generic repository with the entity you want to work wit. Like: `var deviceRepos = new MyGenericRepository<Device>();` and then  `deviceRepos.GetUsingPredicate(d => d.bitIsRemoved == false);` or without generics your example usage is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
return myDataContext.Devices.Where(
        d => yourConditions).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: It is really easy, now I do not see, how I could not find this method. Thank you.